# Regex and the OR operator without grouping in Python?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Here are the cases. I'm looking for the following pattern in a log file.

All strings are in the form of `AB_N` or `CDE_N`. 
`AB` and `CDE` are fixed letters, followed by an underscore. 
`N` can be either 2 or 3 numbers.

I tried `(AB|CDE)_\d{2,3}` but that returns a group. I can't do `\w{2,3}\d{2,3}` because it has to be either `AB` or `CDE` and not `AC` or `FEG`. Omitting the parentheses breaks too. I am sure the solution is simple but I'm new to python and regex and can't figure this out.

Comment: You can wrap the entire thing in a group: `((AB|CDE)_\d{2,3})`, and the first group is `AB_123` and the second is just `AB`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A `?:` inside a parenthesis in a regex makes it non-capturing.  Like so: `(?:AB|CDE)_\d{2,3}`

See docs here:  http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
About a third of the way through it goes over the non-capturing syntax.

Answer (score 4):

The non-capturing group syntax is `(?:...)`.  So do `(?:AB|CDE)_\d{2,3}`.  This is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) along with everything else.

Comment: Oops, a typo.  But it looks like you made one too, since it should be `(?:AB|CDE)`.

Comment: Can I do something like `(?:abc|def|ghi|xyz)`?

Comment: @qed - Yes, you can do anything you would do in regular parens. The `?:` just tells the regex not to treat those parens as a capturing group.